# PowerShell: Nested powershell command to add users to group

Tags: powershell

I want to update a set of AD users with a nested powershell command and I need help with that :(

1. Get all users with a specific attribute (Get-ADUser -Filter 'extensionAttribute1 -like "*"')
2. Add this users to a specific group (Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "GroupNAME" -Member USERNAME)
3. Delete the extension attribute (Set-ADUser –Identity USERNAME -Clear "extensionattribute1")

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can see my commands in the (). Problem is I don't know how to nest this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at how to use a `result set` within a `foreach` loop like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'extensionAttribute1 -like "*"' | foreach {

    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "GroupNAME" -Members $_.samaccountname
    Set-ADUser –Identity $_.samaccountname -Clear "extensionattribute1"
}
```